# Not able to fetch woocommerce variation sales products for particular category products

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

Not able to fetch variation sales product according to particular product category . My code fetch only simple products not variable products.

```
  $cat_id = $_GET['catid'];

  $args = array(    
'post_type'             => 'product',
'post_status'           => 'publish',
'posts_per_page'        =>-1, 
'meta_query'     => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
  array( // Variable products type
        'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
        'value'         => 0,
        'compare'       => '>',
        'type'          => 'numeric'
    ),
    array( // Simple products type   
        'key'           => '_sale_price',
        'value'         => 0,
        'compare'       => '>',
        'type'          => 'numeric'
    )
    ),
'tax_query'             => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'term_id', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
        'terms'         => $cat_id,
        'include_children' => true,
        'operator'      => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
    )
    )

);
$products = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce uses 'product_variation' as the post type for variable products.

So the top level for a variable product is post_type 'product', whereas each variation is post_type 'product_variation'.

Data associated with the particular variation is stored with the appropriate 'product_variation' post.

Comment: No effect, want sales products of simple and variable product for particular category.But when i am not using tax_query it shows both sales  products.